# Cache-friendly multi-dimensional array iteration in D

Tags: caching, multidimensional-array, d

I have a **static** 3-dimensional array in D, generally

```
Struct[WIDTH][HEIGHT][DEPTH] values;
```

with two of these dimensions going into thousands. If I want to iterate over this array accessing memory locations linearly, over which dimension should iterate in the outer loop? `WIDTH` or `DEPTH`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outer loop should be `DEPTH` as evidenced by the following program:

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
  enum X = 6, Y = 4, Z = 2;
  ubyte[X][Y][Z] root;

  foreach (i, ref level3; root) {
    foreach (j, ref level2; level3) {
      foreach (k, ref level1; level2) {
        writefln("%s %s %s: 0x%x", i, j, k, &level1);
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

This prints:

```
0 0 0: 0x7fbfc8b9f0
0 0 1: 0x7fbfc8b9f1
0 0 2: 0x7fbfc8b9f2
0 0 3: 0x7fbfc8b9f3
0 0 4: 0x7fbfc8b9f4
0 0 5: 0x7fbfc8b9f5
0 1 0: 0x7fbfc8b9f6
0 1 1: 0x7fbfc8b9f7
0 1 2: 0x7fbfc8b9f8
0 1 3: 0x7fbfc8b9f9
0 1 4: 0x7fbfc8b9fa
0 1 5: 0x7fbfc8b9fb
0 2 0: 0x7fbfc8b9fc
0 2 1: 0x7fbfc8b9fd
0 2 2: 0x7fbfc8b9fe
0 2 3: 0x7fbfc8b9ff
0 2 4: 0x7fbfc8ba00
0 2 5: 0x7fbfc8ba01
0 3 0: 0x7fbfc8ba02
0 3 1: 0x7fbfc8ba03
0 3 2: 0x7fbfc8ba04
0 3 3: 0x7fbfc8ba05
0 3 4: 0x7fbfc8ba06
0 3 5: 0x7fbfc8ba07
1 0 0: 0x7fbfc8ba08
1 0 1: 0x7fbfc8ba09
1 0 2: 0x7fbfc8ba0a
1 0 3: 0x7fbfc8ba0b
1 0 4: 0x7fbfc8ba0c
1 0 5: 0x7fbfc8ba0d
1 1 0: 0x7fbfc8ba0e
1 1 1: 0x7fbfc8ba0f
1 1 2: 0x7fbfc8ba10
1 1 3: 0x7fbfc8ba11
1 1 4: 0x7fbfc8ba12
1 1 5: 0x7fbfc8ba13
1 2 0: 0x7fbfc8ba14
1 2 1: 0x7fbfc8ba15
1 2 2: 0x7fbfc8ba16
1 2 3: 0x7fbfc8ba17
1 2 4: 0x7fbfc8ba18
1 2 5: 0x7fbfc8ba19
1 3 0: 0x7fbfc8ba1a
1 3 1: 0x7fbfc8ba1b
1 3 2: 0x7fbfc8ba1c
1 3 3: 0x7fbfc8ba1d
1 3 4: 0x7fbfc8ba1e
1 3 5: 0x7fbfc8ba1f
```

Notice that the addresses are increasing in a linear fashion and that the fastest changing index is `X`. So the inner loop represents `X` and the outer loop represents `Z`.

Answer (score 3):

yaz' answer is perfectly fine. But to memoize the semantics, it might help to think of array declarations being 'left associative' - that is, `ubyte value[X][Y]` declares an

(array of length Y of element type (array of length X of element type (ubyte)))

or `(((ubyte value)[X])[Y])`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all D compilers are doing unrolling automatically as part of the optimization. At least that is an unconfirmed information someone passed to me on IRC.

Logically, the first loop should be the dimension that you know you wont have many values. The inner loops should be for those dimensions that you mentioned will go into thousands.